# Count the tweets from time x until time y

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to make an application using Twitter API, and it would be very helpful to be able to count the number of tweets that mention a given word in an specified time (from time x to time y). Usually this time will be short, just a matter of seconds.

Does any one know a way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Twitter streaming API to collect all tweets that include a specific word, and then count the tweets that match. The streaming API lets you track up to 400 words.